# Use PHP to Update a Value in a MySQLi Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've written the below function to update a value in a MySQLi database table.  I'm not receiving any errors, but the value is also not updating.  I can't see what's going wrong.

```
function update_hangman_highscore($user, $user_highscore){
    echo 'Update highscore called.  High score to update is '.$user_highscore.' for '.$user;
    $db = "localhost";
    $user = "phpuser";
    $pwd = "Ninja1995";
    $database = "ninja_comments";
    $link = mysqli_connect($db, $user, $pwd)or die(mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_select_db($link, $database) or die(mysqli_error($link));
   $result = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users SET hangman_highscore = '$user_highscore' WHERE username = '$user';") or die(mysqli_error());
}
```

I'm calling the function using:

```
if($_SESSION['score'] > $_SESSION['user_highscore']){
    update_hangman_highscore($_SESSION['user'], $_SESSION['score']);
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Too many wrong guesses.  You died, but you also achieved a new personal highscore!';
}
```

I've used an echo in the function (see first line) to verify that the function is being called. This also tells me that $high_score and $user parameters are being passed properly.  I can also replace these variables with actual values, and the function works properly.  So at this point, I'm also out of troubleshooting ideas.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you're using MySQLi, please, please, please learn to use prepared statements/bind variables

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `$user` variable twice, and that's rewriting the value. You should rename it.

Try with

```
function update_hangman_highscore($user, $user_highscore){
    echo 'Update highscore called.  High score to update is '.$user_highscore.' for '.$user;
    $db = "localhost";
    $db_user = "phpuser";
    $pwd = "Ninja1995";
    $database = "ninja_comments";
    $link = mysqli_connect($db, $db_user, $pwd)or die(mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_select_db($link, $database) or die(mysqli_error($link));
   $result = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users SET hangman_highscore = '$user_highscore' WHERE username = '$user';") or die(mysqli_error());
}
```